# clip linestring by length

Tags: postgis, distance, linestring, clip

Is there a way to clip a linestring based on distance?
For example, linestring from a to b is 150 meters. I would like to get the linestring from a to a point that is is 75 meters away from a following the a-b linestring.

What I have thought until now is to get the line NpointCount and start adding together small line segments until I get close to 75 meters, but still, how am I supposed to add the final line segment?

I hope I am making sense here..

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PostGIS it's a two-stage process. First you need to find the overall length of your line geometry with [ST_length()](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Length.html)

Say that produces a value of 150. Then you need to divide your desired length, 75, by the total length, giving you 0.5. Finally, with that value call [ST_Line_Interpolate_Point()](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html) or  [ST_Line_Substring()](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Line_Substring.html) to return the substring rather than a point.

Comment: thx, i ll give it a try!

Comment: My bad, I meant ST_Line_Substring() http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Line_Substring.html _not_ ST_Line_Interpolate_Point()

Comment: Right, your suggestion works fine but it seems that postgis has problems converting some specific multilinestrings into linestrings which is necessary before calling the st_line_substring function. Is there a way to come around this postgis issue?

Comment: If your lines are as multilines, you'll need to split them up first. You can use ST_Dump (http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) and pass the results into your query.

Comment: You are right, some of my lines have a double ending like a double fork and that is probably causing trouble to postgis...Anyway, thank you very much for your help!